# What is the difference in meaning between "I want to do something" and "I want to have done something"?

Tags: infinitives, perfect-aspect, infinitive-clauses

In the 12th episode of the 2nd season of *Suits* one of the characters said the following.

> **I want to have talked** to everyone of my clients by the end of the day.

That's the first time I've seen the construction *want to have done something*. I'd like to know what the difference is between *I want to do something* and *I want to have done something*. Would the meaning of the sentence change if the character said

> **I want to talk** to everyone of my clients by the end of the day?

I've referred to the grammar books I have and I couldn't find anything addressing the difference between the constructions.

Comment: I like the question, and mentioned the source but when I Googled the string ["to everyone of my clients by the end of the day"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+everyone+of+my+clients+by+the+end+of+the+day%22&sxsrf=ALiCzsbOW419C4lTGPR6AaqMQWkYvjKU5w%3A1656076832376&ei=ILq1YvfIFtXd7_UPyr2AuAc&ved=0ahUKEwj32MH6lsb4AhXV7rsIHcoeAHcQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22to+everyone+of+my+clients+by+the+end+of+the+day%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgAToECCMQJ0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFCUB1iFM2DvOGgAcAB4AIABoAGIAf8EkgEDNC4ymAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) (which is a bit clumsy) only one result turned up.

Comment: Are you sure that you transcribed the line correctly?

Comment: Absolutely sure. Here is a link to the transcripts of the episode https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=189&t=11495&sid=9d2a32db8a62d69dce472bf42ffcdf0d

Comment: Yep, found the show online and listened to Harvey, a lawyer, saying the line around 16 minute mark.

Comment: The character is focusing on the achievement of a target ('to have talked') rather than the acts (to talk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the difference in meaning between the two sentences is negligible.
P.S I substituted "everyone of" with "all" for stylistic reasons.

1. I want to **talk** to all my clients by the end of the day

The speaker expresses an *intention* in the present (*I want*) that refers to an action that is either in progress or is about to start. We know this because of the time expression, “by the end of the day”.

2. I want to **have talked** to all my clients by the end of the day.

The speaker uses the perfect infinitive to **emphasise** the completion of the action at some point in the future.  Both sentences are grammatical and carry the same meaning. I don't see any significant difference.

> The [perfect infinitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked) can refer to something that will be completed at a point in the future:
>
> *We hope **to have finished** the building works by the end of March.*
>
> Source: *Cambridge Dictionary*

The perfect infinitive can be used without referring to a specific time period and for actions that are repeated. The following excerpt is taken from an article by *The Guardian*

> From the cloth and dyes of a T-shirt to the buttons on jeans, he’s committed to the brand’s holistic approach. “Eventually, when five or six factories have made different component parts of a garment, [we want **to have visited and checked** all of those elements](https://www.theguardian.com/huelwear-clothes-for-the-conscious/2022/apr/25/guilt-free-apparel-the-ethical-clothing-brand-providing-an-alternative-to-fast-fashion),” he says.

I think in the above situation, the use of the perfect infinitive is preferable because the *habitual* act of inspecting and checking each piece that goes into the garment began in the past and extends to the present. Note that the co-founder uses the present perfect in “*when five or six factories ***have made*** different component parts*” so the perfect infinitive “**to have visited and checked**” is euphonious and totally appropriate.